the number of attempts

When I punched the punchbag I felt pain - after one punch

Whenever I punch the punchbag I feel pain -  It might be I throw more than one punch each time before I feel pain, correct?



I think the tense shift (Past to Present) is an irrelevant distraction. In both cases it's only a tendency to assume "whenever" implies possibly multiple punches on each occasion when punching led to pain (and the corollary that "when" implies single punches caused pain). So don't stake your life on any such distinction - to a considerable extent, both interpretations are a least "credible" for both phrasings. The distinction seems more than it is simply because you're presenting two very similar utterances and asking people to "spot the difference".

When I drink vodka, I get sick. When I drank vodka, I got sick.


It hurts after I punched it once. 2) Is ambiguous, it could be as 1 or it could be after multiple punches - a work out.


Side note: in American English it is a punching bag.

No. Not correct. "When I punched" could mean "When I threw a punch" or it could mean "When I was doing my workout with the punching bag throwing multiple punches".  "Whenever I punch" could having either of those meanings as well, with the addition of "whenever", meaning on every such act of punching, whether it was throwing  a punch or doing a punching workout with multiple punches.  whenever has nothing to do with the number of punches involved in each incidence of punching.

The verb "punch" usually means a single strike, but it might mean several.  Consider: "The angry child punched, bit, and kicked the teacher."  In context you'd probably understand that to mean multiple punches, bites and kicks.
In the case of the punchbag, "When I punched the punchbag"  might refer to a single hit, or it might refer to a training session.  "The boxer punched his punchbag for 45 minutes each evening". So while the most likely meaning of 1) is a single punch, the verb doesn't have to mean that. Likewise for 2)
Other verbs have different semantics.

I mean that if we talk about something that happened only once in the past for instance "When she kicked me I ran" rather implies only one kick and then I ran. On the other hand if something repeated is described "When she kicks me I run' here it happens rather vague and it might be more than one kick each time, correct?

Well, we could sit here all day and go through the semantics of every verb. In the case in your comment, "when she kicked me" could be one or more actual leg motions; one or more "kicks".  The number of kicks is probably not relevant If you are telling someone about the time when someone assaulted you, you are not too concerned with counting the number of kicks. The difference is not the number of kicks, but the tense (particular past time, or general fact)

when = at the time that; on the occasion that -- whenever - at all times/occasions that -- The when/whenever gives no information about the number of punches thrown.

when I punch is a generalization about whatever "I punch" is understood to mean: a single punch or a session of punching.
whenever I punch is also a generalization but it emphasizes multiple occasions on which the activity occurred, whether the activity is a single punch or a punching session.
whenever indicates that  multiple pieces of data are involved in the generalization.  With when the speaker might have generalized from only a single experience.
Consider:

I have been taking the medicine for a month.  When I drink wine,  I get a rash.
I have been taking the medicine for a month. Whenever I drink wine, I get a rash.

In both instances the speaker might have had some wine on multiple occasions. Only the second, with whenever, explicitly expresses that  multiple occasions have been involved in the generalization.
Simply put, we do not use whenever with a single experience.  If we've been to a restaurant once in our life, we don't say "Whenever I go there, I order mushroom pizza."
